# Variable Assigning from Api to field - ReactJS , Javascript

Tags: json, node.js, reactjs, api

For examplpe I am fetching the record through Json and in success function am storing the return data in localstorage to use

Output Json like
[{"1":"Core"},{"2":"Moderate"},{"3":"Remote"}]

It's returning as expected
but I can't populate the data in drop down, if i hard coded the same json it's working. Thanks in advance please help me to resolve.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'http://test.com',
        //type: 'POST',
        //data :Editorcontent,
        success: function (data) {
let fieldes = JSON.parse(data)

    localStorage.setItem('one',fieldes)
        },
        error: function () {
            alert(url);
        }
    });
    var selected = localStorage.getItem('one');
    //selected = [{"1":"Core"},{"2":"Moderate"},{"3":"Remote"}]
    //selected = selected.replace('\'',"'");
    console.log(selected);

 var editor = {
ajax: '',
ajaxFiles: '',
struct: {
buttons: ['top', 'bottom'] // buttons
},
fields: [
{
  label: "Branch Name",
  name: "DefaultBranchID",
  values: selected,
  type: 'select'


},
 {
 label: "Country:",
  name: "CountryID",
  type: 'multiselect', 
  attrs: [
    {'pattern': '^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$'}
  ]
},
```

"selected" is the variable am assigning
OutPut for Branch Nam Drop down :-[O/p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aZUR.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post your code as text in your question, not as an image.

Comment: Done please help me on this

Comment: Can you show the code where you are updating to reactjs component?